# Open Graph object internationalization: no scrape / missing parameter fb_locale

Tags: graph, localization, internationalization, facebook-opengraph

I am having trouble with internationalization of my open graph objects. I am providing the og:locale as well as the og:locale:alternate tags, but Facebook does not scrape my objects in different locales. In the object debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug i can see the og:locale:alternate are parsed and it shows them as an array. But clicking one of them results in a scrape without any parameter. Neither fb_locale nor locale nor the header X-Facebook-Locale are provided.

Here is one of the example objects:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_DE">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="181576101937079">
<meta property="og:type" content="APP_NAMESPACE:level">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/?ogObjType=level&amp;ogObjId=0_0&amp;ogObjVariant=">
<meta property="og:title" content="Tree House Level 1">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:determiner" content="the">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://URLTOIMAGE">
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

And when I add fb_locale=de_DE by hand, it returns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_DE">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="181576101937079">
<meta property="og:type" content="APP_NAMESPACE:level">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/?ogObjType=level&amp;ogObjId=0_0&amp;ogObjVariant=">
<meta property="og:title" content="Baumhaus Level 1">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:determiner" content="the">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://URLTOIMAGE">
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell why Facebook does not scrape the localized versions of my objects?

Comment: Same thing happening here. Did anybody figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Hi Martin. I'm having the same problem and created my own thread (before finding yours). Have a look at mine (with more questions concerning this topic): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511143/how-to-implement-internationalization-of-og-tags

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. 
OG-tags:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_GB" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="ru_RU" />
```

If I did

```
curl -X POST -F "id=http://gorokhovsky.nampohui.ru" -F "scrape=true" -F "locale=en_GB" "https://graph.facebook.com"
```

or locale=en_US

my server got request from FB, and I receive a correct answer.

```
{"url":"http:\/\/gorokhovsky.nampohui.ru\/","type":"website","title":"Surfingbird - your personal web!","locale":{"locale":"en_us","alternate":["en_gb","ru_ru","fr_fr"]},"image":[{"url":"http:\/\/surfingbird.ru\/img\/logo-mailru2.gif?v=1"}],"description":"We pick interesting websites, photos and videos that you\u2019ll like.","site_name":"Surfingbird.ru","updated_time":"2013-02-27T15:04:20+0000","id":"356024197844717","application":{"id":"179736405468568","name":"Gorokhovsky2","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/apps\/application.php?id=179736405468568"}}
```

But if I set locale=fr_FR or ru_RU, I receive

```
"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}
```

My server didn't get request from FB

If I set locale=ru_ru or fr_fr, it worked like locale=en_US

I think FB incorrect working with case of locale's characters

Answer (score 0):

Try using the lower case for locale en_us instead of en_US.